# Java Generics -- Assigning a list of subclass to a list of superclass

Tags: java, generics

I have a basic question regarding assignment of a list of subclass to a list of superclass.

So I have something like the following:

```
Class B extends A;

List <B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
List <A> aList = bList;
```

Why does this last assignment fail? Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitl)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To explain this, let me substitute "B" with Integer and "A" with Number. This is just to make it a little easier to explain.

```
Class Integer extends Number;

List <Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List <Number> nList = iList // will fail
```

The reason this would fail is because nList can take any Number -- it can take Integer, it can take Double, or for that matter any subclass of Number. However, this is not true for iList. You cannot add a Double to iList because it accepts only Integer and its subclasses. Hope this helps explain it to you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation. I think I follow now.

Comment: Also look at Jon Skeet's wonderful response in the link that Daniel Pryden mentions in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 11):

When you declare a List of items of type A, only items of type A can be added or removed from the List. If you need to include subclasses of A, use the generic wildcard `? extends A` to indicate so. Your code should therefore be:

```
List <? extends A> aList = bList;
```

Answer (score 4):

`List<B>` is not `List<A>`:

Through example: let say you have `class B1 extends A{}` and `class B2 extends A{}`
then (if you would be able to do that:

```
List<B1> b1 = new AList<B1>();
List<A> a = b1;

List<B2> b2 = new AList<B2>();
```

by the hypothesis, you should be able to do
    a.add(new B2())
but this is wrong.

If you try the same thing but using `arrays` instead of lists, it will compile and throw exception in runtime.

We say that arrays are *covariant* and generics are *invariant*.

to make the code compile you have the wite it:

```
List<? extends A> a = b;
```

this says that a is a list of some *subtype* of A. _But you don know which one. Because of that you can't do `a.put(X)`

Answer (score 1):

`List<B>` and `List<A>` are `invariant` type. What you need is `covariant` type. In this case, it is `List<? extends A>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because generics are **strict type safe**.

You can have

```
List<? extends A> aList = bList;
```

It says `aList` can hold list of any type which is an `A`

Answer (score 0):

Because `List<B>` does not extend `List<A>`. For example, `Integer` extends `Number` and so does `Long`. So `List<Number>` can contain both `Integer` and `Long`. So if you assign `List<Integer>` to `List<Number>` you will be able to add `Long` to your list of integers.

You can declare

```
List<? super B> superB;
```

And that would allow assignment to superB of any list that contains B and its super classes.
But it's not the same as in your case `aList=bList`.

or

```
List<? extends A> extendsA;
```

Examples

```
    List<? super Integer> superA;
    superA = new ArrayList<Number>();

    List<? extends Number> extendsNumber;
    extendsNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

While at first glance you might think that

```
Class B extends A;

List <B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
List <A> aList = bList;
```

should work, the problem is obvious when you imagine actually using these lists:

```
A something = new A();
aList.add( something ); // Should work because aList is a list of A's
```

but `aList` was assigned to `bList`, so that should be the same as

```
bList.add( something ); // Here's the problem
```

`bList.add()` takes a `B`, but `something` is an `A`, and an `A` is not a `B`!

And that's why generics should be (and are) strict type safe.